# Newsletter code not updating page

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

I have updated the `subscribe.phtml` file and cleared the cache as well reindexed everything but it has not worked. I have also go template path hints enabled and it give the path below.

`frontend/default/magezon/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml`

which is the file I have changed. I am at a loss here. Any help will be really appreciated.

I am using Magento 1.9...

Comment: Try from different browser, sometime browser cache plays role.

Comment: I have tried it in two different browsers and it isnt working. Also I had cleared the cache in all possible scenarios i.e. from magento back end (all kinds of cache) as well as local machine etc...